# What is the meaning of "clocking" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

The federal Minimum wage in the US is $7.25 per hour. Ten states have higher minimum wages with Rhode Island `clocking` in 50 cents higher at $7.75.

What is the meaning of clocking? Why not use "closing"?

Answer (score 5):

I think the existing answers are potentially misleading. It's true that *to clock in* originally gained currency in the 40s in respect of workers recording the time of starting work (often, in a factory, where they might also *clock **on***, and *clock **out*** or *clock **off*** when they finished work).

But in recent decades, the specific phrasal verb *clock **in*** has acquired another sense. It's now often used to mean *record / achieve a "score" in a competition* (where OP's "minimum wage comparison" can be seen as a "competition").

This usage is particularly favoured where the "score" values are time-based, but OP's example is by no means uncommon. Another very similar idiom is [*clock **up***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/clock-up) *- to reach a particular number or amount*.

Note that the more common phrasing here would be *with Rhode Island clocking in **at** 50 cents higher*. In such contexts, *to clock in* is usually followed by ***at*** [the actual recorded value], but in this specific case that would be clumsy - since the actual value is expressed as *50 cents higher **at** $7.75*, we'd have two occurrences of the same preposition in undesirably close proximity.

---

Having said all that, I agree with other answers/comments making the point that OP's cited usage *could* (but doesn't *have to*) be seen as a punning allusion to the factory timekeeping origin of the expression.

Finally, I'll just say that if the writer had used *clocking **up*** instead of ***in***, he wouldn't have had to think about whether to follow it with ***at*** (which is rarely used after ***up***). But then his pun would be diluted.

Comment: I never thought of "clocking in at" as related to time cards. I thought it was related to timing someone in a race, and thus was a measure of achievement.

Comment: @Wayne: Hah! So *you* at least didn't need my answer to set the record straight regarding *current* usage! Technically speaking you're actually right - OED's first citation for *To accomplish or attain (a certain time or speed) in a race; to register (a time, distance, etc.) on a clock or dial.* is 1892. It's not until 1914 that they cite an instance of *With in, on (off, out): to register one's arrival at (or departure from) work by means of a mechanical device combined with a clock*. Then there's the slang ***clock**: (orig. US) watch or observe; look at, notice* first recorded in 1942.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it as "clocking in", not just "clocking", and I believe you'd understand why.

Though you can write "closing in" instead of "clocking in" and the meaning will still be roughly the same, using "clocking in" makes the line much more interesting, in my opinion.

Workers usually need to ***[clock in](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clock+in) and [clock out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clock+out)*** of their work. The basic sense of ***[clock](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/clock_10)*** is to measure or record something (though it's usually about the speed). By playing with words, the sentence jumps off the page and puts me into the context of labors and minimum wages instantly.

---

Here are the definitions for "clock in" and "clock out" from the Free Dictionary:

> **[clock in](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clock+in)** - register one's arrival at work
>   **[clock out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clock+out)** - register one's departure from work

Comment: Indeed, I think the writer was being punny, as you indicate.

Comment: @J.R. What is `being punny`?

Comment: Let me answer this on behalf on J.R. To me, the phrase "clocking in" is there just to make the sentence sound more interesting. The two sentences can be understood perfectly even after "clocking in" has been removed from the second sentence. The meaning (which I though you might already knew), is that the minimum wage in the US is $7.25/hour. There are 10 states that have higher minimum wages, and Rhode Island is one of them. If you worked there (Rhode Island), you will get paid at least $7.75/hour.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo - _Punny_ is simply slang for "forming a pun" (usually an amusing one). The word is a portmanteau of _pun_ and _funny_

Answer (score 0):

> The federal Minimum wage in the US is $7.25 per hour. Ten states have higher minimum wages with Rhode Island clocking in 50 cents higher at $7.75.

It's the time you spent working in a factory or office. If you say you're on clock, that means you're in working hours.

Comment: Thanks, does that somehow mean `I work(on clock) here for one hour and will get $7.75`?